# jquery attr not working properly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i am trying to use ajax in form so that it checks the data base with a php script and then i would like to change the values of some disabeled fields in my form but it doest seem to work although the ajax is working and the jquery too .

heres the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>F2 Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkDB(){
            var itr = document.getElementById( "itr" ).value;
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'checkDB.php',
                data : {itr: itr},
                success: function(response){
                   $("v_id").attr("value","hi");
                  }
            });
       }
</script>
```

heres the html form snippet :

```
<form name="f2" method="post" action="form_submission2.php">
    ITR:<input type="text" name="itr" id="itr" onkeypress="checkDB()" /><br />
    Vehicle ID:<input type="text" name="id" id="v_id" value="" disabled><br />
```

Comment: Typo: You're missing the `#` on the `id` selector. Also use `val()`, not `attr('value', x)`. Try `$("#v_id").val("hi");`

Answer (score 2):

The `value` **attribute** is not the value of the input, it's the *default* value of the input. The `value` **property** is the value of the input.

To set the value, use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val):

```
$("v_id").val("hi");
```

*(Or you could use `.prop("value", "hi")`, but idiomatically, you'd use `val`.)*

But note also that you're missing the `#` on the `id` selector, so:

```
$("#v_id").val("hi");
```

---

Re

> still not working

Yes, it does:

```js
function checkDB() {
  var itr = document.getElementById("itr").value;
  // Simulate ajax with timeout
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("#v_id").val("hi");
  }, 10);
}

checkDB();
```

```html
<form name="f2" method="post" action="form_submission2.php">
  ITR:
  <input type="text" name="itr" id="itr" onkeypress="checkDB()" />
  <br />Vehicle ID:
  <input type="text" name="id" id="v_id" value="" disabled>
  <br />
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @RatikBhat: Yes, it works. There may well be some **other**, unrelated problem with your code, but the above works.

Comment: Yes, it worked thank you for the answer it was a typo (missing #)

Answer (score 2):

Please check the code under the **success** :

Change

```
 $("v_id").attr("value","hi");
```

To

```
 $("#v_id").val("hi");
```